# how to pass argument in getall() in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am just going to fetch related tags of bbc news site. but i get empty data. using getall() method. how can i get only data included tags?

```py
import scrapy


class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'author'

    start_urls = ['https://www.bbc.com/news/technology']

    def parse(self, response):
        author_page_links = response.css('.gel-layout__item .gs-c-promo-body div > a')
        yield from response.follow_all(author_page_links, self.parse_author)
        
    def parse_author(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).getall(),
            
        yield {
            'name':extract_with_css('.ssrcss-ukwdbg-SectionWrapper .ssrcss-d7aixc-ClusterItems li a::text'),
        }
```

Comment: Presumably your css selectors are wrong. Have you checked them?

Comment: No, I am getting data but some fields in the URL are empty. That's why they return empty dictionaries. But I a use 0nly get(), then it returns data without an empty dictionary. but it contains only the first word of each article related fields. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: you can try this code on your end and will get my point.